# Basics! How to get rid of protruding face that overlaps another object

Tags: extrude

A hopefully simple solution for a newbie like me. So i created a cube, deleted the top face, and then created the roof using a single plane and mirror modifier. Once i lined up the roof to the walls i had to fill in the space in the center between the roof and walls. My solution was to extrude it up and then do away with teh excess face that is protruding passed the roof. But to no avail i couldnt find anything... What is your guys's solution? Or maybe a different method all around?

[image: protruding object]

Comment: I think you need to check some hard surface modeling tutorials on youtube, just to learn some basic stuff.. (btw are you trying to make a box with a roof?)

Comment: ive spent a lot of time on tutorials, but its difficult sometimes to follow when a large majority of them are of previous versions of blender. Not to mention a large portion of the learning process is trial and error. So after trying to imitate desired effects through tuts and running into an issue i figured id be able to come here to figure out where im going wrong.. or do i have the wrong idea here

Comment: and essentially im trying to slice off the excess of whats going beyond the top of the roof to fill what used to be an empty triangular space between the roof and house walls.. if that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make a box with a roof, you can simply

- add a cube
- loop cut and slide it in the half like this:

[image]

- select the middle top edge and move it upward

[image]